# Visual Studio 2010/ASP.NET 2.0/WebUserControl - __DataBinding__control appears multiple times in intellisense for the WebUserControl

Tags: visual-studio-2010, data-binding, asp.net-2.0, webusercontrol

as the title says it, I'm seeing some weird properties on the intellisense of my webusercontrol (_*DataBinding*_control##).

My webusercontrol binds data from our database. The calling page just passes parameters and then the webusercontrol fetches data and binds them to it's gridviews and dropdownlists.

Should I be worried that I'm doing something wrong or is this normal for a webusercontrol?

I tried searching the net with the following keywords: "asp.net webusercontrol _*DataBinding*_control", "webusercontrol __DataBinding", etc... but I don't see any relevant articles.

Please advise. 
Thank you.

Comment: anyone know about this or has experienced this?

Comment: please help me understand why this is happening. thank you.